# SecItemCopyMatching without FaceID via kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly

Tags: ios, face-id

I'm trying to unlock data from the keychain / secure enclave via FaceID and make it accessible for the duration of the User session (without additional unlocks).

[Per the documentation for kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattraccessibleafterfirstunlockthisdeviceonly):

> After the first unlock, the data remains accessible until the next restart. This is recommended for items that need to be accessed by background applications. Items with this attribute do not migrate to a new device.

Yet, whenever I call **SecItemCopyMatching()** ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1398306-secitemcopymatching)), I'm ***always*** prompted to perform a FaceID authorization.

Can someone explain what I might be doing wrong (or misunderstanding)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data protection class and the access control flags assigned to a keychain item are separate.

In your question you have detailed the data protection class that you have assigned, but the behaviour you are describing is resulting from the access control flags that were specified.

The data protection class refers to the lock state *of the device*, not the *keychain item*.

If you specify one or more [of these values](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secaccesscontrolcreateflags) then the specified authentication (biometric and/or passcode) is required *each time the keychain item is accessed*.

If you only want the user to authenticate their presence the first time the item is accessed then you could specify no access control for the item and use the local authentication framework directly. Set a flag once the user has successfully authenticated and do not prompt them again in that session (or until a certain time hasn't elapsed or whatever logic you like).

Comment: Thank you; I was hoping that I could have the best of both worlds -- require `biometryCurrentSet` but also allow the data to be accessed via `FirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly`

Comment: If you are going to use `biometryCurrentSet` then you should probably consider using `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly`